# Creating a new csv from malformed csv (containing LF and CR characters in between a field)

Tags: regex, powershell, csv, carriage-return, linefeed

I have a 4 column csv file that has one of its columns spread across multiple lines as seen below:

```
Number#,Scenes,OkOrFail,Time(ms)  
1,com.mine[scenario->GRADE_1:thsi is test is request from Eol   ],OK,3613
2,com.mine[scenario->GRADE_900:MSA Harvest all losses   ],OK,1325  
14,com.mine[scenario->GRADE_450:Great lamps Entity with xbars  
Entity used SplitEnt  
Model : silicon8],OK,930  
15,com.mine[scenario->GRADE_985:request picking from the transmitter

Entity used  silicon-B.E0004  
],FAIL,728  
16,com.mine[scenario->GRADE_120:single query from Receiver with  
],OK,1245
```

To see the unprintable characters in the original file, see below:
[image: bad file with breaks]

I am looking to create a new csv from the original csv after removing the Number# column, extracting just the GRADE_ strings from the Scenes column (GRADE_1, GRADE_900, etc) and keeping the OkOrFail column.

So the new csv will look like this:

```
Scenes,OkOrFail,Time(ms)  
GRADE_1,OK,3613  
GRADE_900,OK,1325  
GRADE_450,OK,930  
GRADE_985,FAIL,728  
GRADE_120,OK,1245
```

I thought constructing a regex to match the entire line and capturing what I want to output later would work. Here is the regex I have:

```
^[0-9]+,.+>([A-Z_0-9]+)[^,]+(,[A-Z]+.*)
```

Now, in Notepad++, this works fine BUT in actual powershell (using version 5.1) only the first two lines work ok.

Here is my code:

```
$origstring = "^[0-9]+,.+>([A-Z_0-9]+)[^,]+(,[A-Z]+.*)"
$testNameOnly = '$1'
$statusAndDuration = '$2'
$csvfile = "C:\small_bad.csv"

(Get-Content $csvfile) | % {
$_ = $_ -replace "Number#,", ''
$_ = $_ -replace $origstring, ($testNameOnly + $statusAndDuration)
Write-Host $_
}
```

And the output is:

```
PS C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> 
Scenes,OkOrFail,Time(ms)
GRADE_1,OK,3613
GRADE_900,OK,1325
14,com.mine[scenario->GRADE_450:Great lamps Entity with xbars
Entity used SplitEnt
Model : silicon8],OK,930
15,com.mine[scenario->GRADE_985:request picking from the transmitter

Entity used  silicon-B.E0004
],FAIL,728
16,com.mine[scenario->GRADE_120:single query from Receiver with
],OK,1245
```

Comment: Your matches span across lines. So, read the whole file in, then run your regex.

Comment: @Wiktor Thank you. I tried the following but I still get the afore-mentioned output:    `$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\csv_parsing\small_bad.csv")  
$content = $content -replace "Number#,", ''  
$content = $content -replace $origstring, ($testNameOnly + $statusAndDuration)  
Write-Host $content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the entire content of the file (instead of a line by line approach) and then do your regex magic:

```
$x = get-content -raw -path Filename1 ; $x -replace $origstring, ($testNameOnly + $statusAndDuration) | set-content -path Filename2
```

Comment: Thank you for the example of capturing the entire content of the file. This was quite helpful in solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As Wiktor Stribiżew comments, `Get-Content` splits the file on newlines and outputs individual lines, but you need your regex to match over multiple lines, so it cannot work. `Get-Content -Raw` causes it to read the entire file into one string including newlines.

My approach is to match the `com.mine[...]` text and wrap it in double quotes, thus making the data a valid CSV which `Import-Csv` can process.

```
(Get-Content -Raw .\test.txt) -replace '(com\.mine\[[^\]]+\])', '"$1"' |
  ConvertFrom-Csv | Format-List
```

NB. Assumes there is no way to put a `]` symbol inside the `com.mine[ data here ]` part.

Comment: Great approach; if you replace `Format-List` with `Select-Object @{n='Scenes'; e={ ($_ -split '[>:]')[1] } }, OkOrFail, Time* | Export-Csv new.csv`, the solution is complete.